# Autoselect select option based on response with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is the way my form group for select looks like.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Active</label>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="activeState" >
        <option ng-value="0" >No</option>
        <option ng-value="1" >Yes</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And the response from api i get is `1` or `0` in my current case `{{activeState}} displays 1`. How to handle this with angular that proper select  will be automatically selected based on response?

If you need any additional information's please let me know and i will provide. Thank you

Comment: what is the problem with current code?

Comment: it doesnt automatically select yes

Comment: Can you show any of the controller code ? I suspect that the return value from the api is an int, while the select value is converted as a string, hence, the element isn't selected. try converting activeState to a string on the api response ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `0` value which is there in `value` attribute is `string` & the value which you got from ajax is `0`(number) so that's why when you try to bind a value on load its not working. This can be easily fix by changing doing `$scope.activeState = '0';`

I'd prefer you to use `ng-options` directive here which does bind value with object `value`

**Markup**

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="activeState" 
   ng-options="yesNo.value as yesNo.name for yesNo in yesNoOptions">
</select>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.yesNoOptions = [
   {name: 'No', value: 0},
   {name: 'Yes', value: 1}
];
$scope.activeState = 0;
```

[**Demo here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/FCKPAF0PoFfORpYtQ8eV?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

The HTML code you've got indicates you're looking for a string. Without seeing the response contents, it's a good guess that you're getting an integer back.

```
http.get(yourUrl,{}).then(function(response){
        $scope.activestate=response.data.toString();//this converts the responseData to a string and assigns it to the model object, replacing the original assignment in your controller
    }, function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
```